# Can a non-constant lower-semi-continuous convex function attain the $-\infty$ value

Tags: continuity, convex-analysis

[This paper](http://annals.math.princeton.edu/wp-content/uploads/annals-v169-n2-p08.pdf) that I am studying asserts in the second paragraph that the only lower-semi-continuous convex function attaining $-\infty$ is the constant $-\infty$ function. However, it seems that the function defined by:
\begin{align}
f(x)=\begin{cases}
-\infty, &x\leq 0\\
\infty, &x>0
\end{cases}
\end{align}
is both convex and lower-semi-continuous. My reasoning is that the epigraph of $f$ is a closed half-plane, which I know to be convex. For lower-semi-continuity, it seems that the only point of concern is $x=0$. But $f(0)=-\infty$, and so it is clear that for all $\epsilon>0$, we have $f(x) \geq f(0)-\epsilon = -\infty$ for any $x\in \mathbb{R}$.

Is there something I'm missing here? Is there something else we assume in the definition of convexity? Am I misinterpreting the statement in the paper?

Comment: The function $f(x)=x$ is usually considered both convex, lower semi-continuous and non-constant.

Comment: @Arthur True, but it does not actually attain $-\infty $, i.e. there is no real $x$ for which $f(x)=\infty$

Comment: Maybe the  sentence "(so that the only function attaining the value −∞ is the constant −∞ function)" is a part of the definition of $Cvx(\Bbb R^n)$? The question is how to define $\infty-\infty$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're correct, and the paper is wrong.